# Random File Generator (again!)

Tags: windows, delphi, random, test-data

I badly need a random file generator that generates a **truly random, non-compressible** dummy files.

I ended up with this delphi code. It *works*, but it's **painfully sloooow**

```
 var
    Buf     : Integer;
    TheFile : TFileStream;
 begin
      TheFile := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmCreate OR fmOpenReadWrite);
      with TheFile do
      begin
           for i := 0 to FileSize do    // Iterate
           begin
                Buf := Random(999999) * i;
                WriteBuffer(Buf, SizeOf(Buf));
           end;    // for
      end;    // with
 end,
```

**My question is: Is there a *fast* random file generator that I can use?** Both Delphi code and/or commandline tools are acceptable as long as:

1. I can run it on Windows *without* manual intervention (I need this for my tests, no intervention is allowed)
2. It's **fast**
3. Files generated is **non-compressible** (ie. compressing the generated file results in no space saving)

---

**EDIT** For those interested, I applied the advice I received here and [made this function](http://pastebin.com/SHwPBFZB), it's fast enough & 7zip has hard time compressing the generated data.

Comment: Profile your code and find out where it is spending the most time.

Comment: He's probably better off using CryptoAPI filling a buffer that is used for writing to the file. There is some C code - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382048.aspx that is a good starting point

Comment: What type is Buf?  What type is i? Should the termination be 'FileSize-1'?

Comment: Please define "fast" and "slow."

Comment: @Petesh: I tried it, but the data generated was highly compressible (thought I'm pretty sure I missed something)

Comment: A Buf type of 'Buf:array [0..4095] of byte;' would be good..

Comment: @Gdhami - fill up a page-sized buffer, then write it.  Writing one int at a time will be slow, use:  Buf:array [0..2047] of integer;

Comment: @RobKennedy: generating 100 files (5 MB each) takes 40 minutes(!) I've seen tools that could do this in few seconds(although not available as command line tools)

Comment: @MartinJames: Good suggestion, I'm trying it now...

Comment: @MartinJames: That did it, please post it as an answer so that I can accept it, thanks!

Comment: Allocate a big block of memory. Fill it with random numbers. Then write it as a whole piece.

Comment: If ever you have a need to write small chunks at a time and it still to be fast, you can use the code from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639531/buffered-files-for-faster-disk-access/5639712#5639712

Comment: Using Random will never create a true random file. With enough background knowledge people can guess your algorithm use the same seed and predict your sequence.

Comment: @PieterB: As I said, I need this to generate random data for my **private test cases**, it's not meant to be shared with others, so no security implication here

Comment: @TheDude You should provide [your code](https://pastebin.com/SHwPBFZB) as an answer to your question! (I nearly missed it ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a 4096-byte page-size, or multiple page-size, buffer.  Writing one integer at a time will be slow.

Comment: Agreed. The problem here is I/O.

Comment: @ChrisThornton In fact it won't be the I/O that will be the bottleneck, but the overhead of calling `WriteFile`. The OS will have a buffering layer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my [generate_random_file.py](https://bitbucket.org/rsnitsch/filehasher/src/205f2bf55b27d53aa3970592a8ffb12c11a6fc30/testdata/generate_random_file.py) script (Python 3) that I used to generate test data in a project of mine.

- It works both on Linux and Windows.
- It is very fast, because it uses [`os.urandom()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.urandom) to generate the random data in chunks of 256 KiB instead of generating and writing each byte separately.

Comment: @Will: How dare you call this spam? Yes, I have posted this answer in 3 related questions, but this is generally considered to be acceptable (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17455/is-it-ok-that-i-just-posted-my-same-answer-to-several-related-questions). If you want me to improve my answer, then tell me why. Simply deleting it is bad practice.